# Push Error GitKraken

Tags: gitkraken

Can't push may changes to the repo with GitKraken.

[image]

I have the credentials CORRECT. Since is a private repo, I had to clone the repo via URL. I did that with my user (authorized of course). I DID commits before, and now I just cant push again.
I'm the only one working on this breanch.
Any thoughts?

Comment: By the way, I CAN see the repo with the user on github (obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission problem. Turn's out I had no permission to writte.